# pathos.multiprocessing returning same value for a parallelized random simulation

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pathos

I'm trying to parallelize a simulation that is replicated many times using `pathos.multiprocessing`. However, the `map` function keeps returning the same value for each iteration. Perhaps my understanding of `map` is incorrect? This is what my code looks like:

```py
def simulate(_):
    # simulation occurs here
    return result

reps = 10

# without parallelization
serial_result = []
for _ in range(reps):
    result.append(simulate())
print(result) 
# prints [5.6, 5.8, 4.2, 5.6, 5.8, 5.0, 12.4, 5.8, 4.4, 4.6]

# with parallelization
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
pool = Pool(10)
parallel_result = pool.map(simulate, range(reps))
print(parallel_result) 
# prints [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]
```

Comment: I've had the same issue myself... `multprocessing` reuses the same random seed, you have to make sure the seed is different for each process.

Comment: I see. Adding `np.random.seed()` to my `simulate` function seems to have fixed my issue. I suppose using the replication number as the seed would still allow me to reproduce my results?

Comment: Yes, you should still be able to seed your calculations.  Note that there's both a numpy random seed and a python random seed.